# How to edit loop cuts

Tags: edit-mode

I cannot work out how to change the number of cuts after I have exited edit mode and then later wanting to change the number of loop cuts re selected edit model as the panel bottom of screen has then disappeared.

There is a small panel near top left of screen but changing number of cuts there doesn't make any changes.

Thanks

Comment: You can't dynamically alter the edits you've made after the fact. The panel at the bottom can be called back with F9 if you haven't done anything else, but after you take any other action, you either have to undo, or select your loops manually (with Alt+Shift+Left Click on edges), dissolve (Ctrl-X) and do them again.

Comment: You can't! As soon as you start some other action you won't be able to edit any previous one. If you haven't done anything else apart from clicking elsewhere in the window you can bring the dialog back with F9 but if you've come out of Edit mode you'd have to hit undo (Ctrl-Z) until you got back to a time before you did the loop cut and start again.

Answer (score 2):

Once you make the cuts, they become part of the mesh. You can't directly change their count after the deed is done. But you can remove existing loops and add new ones, assuming you don't need them to be evenly spaced. If you do, then just remove each loop, and re-make the correct amount the same way you made the original ones.

To delete an edge loop, select one edge in it, and do *Select edge loop*, then Ctrl+X to *Dissolve*. To insert a new one, you can just make a single edge loop between two already existing ones.

Comment: Thanks every one. Understood. Either try F9 (key) or delete edge loop or start again. I my situation (creating a cylinder bent through 180 degrees its simply to restart it.   BTW once I have bent a cylinder into a semi circle is it possible to distort the bend by selecting one loop cut and dragging?